# are all wifi connections in ubuntu treated as 'public' automatically?

Tags: wireless

i just booted up ubuntu for first time and connected to wifi. i've come from windows where when you connect to wifi you choose to make it a 'home' or 'public' connection. i can't find this option anywhere so does ubuntu automatically treat all wifi connections as 'public'. i use from a router in the stairwell of a small apartment block used by others,  so when i was using windows op system i always made the wifi 'public'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it, "public", "work" and "home" simply turn on differing levels of a firewall-like scheme, allowing or denying services, supposedly keeping your computer safe from attack.

If you're interested in this type of "protection", you should investigate a Linux firewall configuration program like `firestarter`, which will allow you to do the same thing, but with much more control and understanding.

In my opinion, this isn't much use compared to running Linux and using WPA encryption to the router. If you really want security, get an encrypted VPN like airvpn (airvpn.org) for a low cost. If the connection to the router isn't encrypted, get a VPN, else everything you send is easy to intercept.

Comment: i figured the windows options would be irrelevant in linux, thanks for clarifying. i'll check out airvpn.

Comment: A firewall is perhaps more useful in stopping outbound connections as it is in stopping inbound. Ports could be wide open, but if there's no server software running on your machine to respond, nothing's gonna happen. The problem with Windows is that there's lots of bad stuff that could be running on your machine that would respond!